# Fetch records that has all specific relationships

Tags: sql, laravel, join, many-to-many, relationship

I have the next schema:

```
nutrients
|id|label        |type
|1 |Avocado      |fats
|2 |Cooked shrimp|proteins
|3 |Raw oatmeal  |carbohydrates
|4 |Chocolate    |fats

recipes
|id|label
|1 |Something with Avocado
|2 |Something w Avocado, chocolate and raw oatmeal

nutrient_recipe
|nutrient_id|recipe_id
|1          |1
|1          |2
|3          |2
|4          |2
```

And I want to fetch only the recipe that has exactly certain nutrient types.
For example:

1. I want a recipe that has only fats.

It should return Something with Avocado (id: 1)

---

2. I want a recipe that has only fats and carbohydrates.

It should return Something w Avocado, chocolate and raw oatmeal (id: 2)

*How can I achieve this?*

I'm working with **Laravel** it would be great if you take advantage of **Eloquent**.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @GordonLinoff

I could achieve the next code:

```php
App\Models\Recipe::whereHas('nutrients', function ($query) {
    $query->havingRaw("sum(case when nutrients.type = 'fats' then 1 else 0 end) > 0")
        ->havingRaw("sum(case when nutrients.type not in ('fats') then 1 else 0 end) = 0")
        ->groupBy('recipes.id')
        ->select('recipes.id');
})
```

obviusly this code seams to belong to a filtered search, so I hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Here is an example for "fats":

```
select nr.recipe_id
from nutrient_recipe nr join
     nutrients n
     on nr.nutrient_id = n.id
group by nr.recipe_id
having sum(case when n.type = 'fats' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when n.type not in ('fats') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

The first `having` condition says there is at least one nutrient that is "fats".  The second says there are none.

You can easily extend this with more `having` clauses:

```
select nr.recipe_id
from nutrient_recipe nr join
     nutrients n
     on nr.nutrient_id = n.id
group by nr.recipe_id
having sum(case when n.type = 'fats' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when n.type = 'carbohydrates' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when n.type not in ('fats', 'carbohydrates') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

Comment: in the declarations of cases, nr.type sould be n.type, isn't it?

Comment: @FranciscoDaniel . . . Yes.  That was the wrong alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
$get = nutrients::whereIn('type', ['type one', 'type two'])->get();
```

then save it in the other table.